# DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialised

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress, delphi-xe3

I am running *Delphi XE3 (Ultimate Edition)*, MySQL database and this is the error I get when a click `Test Connection`.

[image]

As a response, I located the libmysql library in my xampp directory and copied it over to my System32 directory. This does not work however.

Which libraries/drivers is this message referring to and what is the correct directory to place them in?

libmysql version - 5.5.16.0

Comment: Are you using a 64 bits Windows? if that is the case you must copy the libmysql file to the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message states that the library could be:

- missing;
- not properly installed; or
- of the wrong version

I googled for the library and came across this [blog post](http://wiltonsoftware.com/posts/view/getting-embarcadero-dbexpress-mysql-working-dbx-error-driver-not-initialized) which discusses that aforementioned error message and provides a more recent version of the libmysql library which is to be placed in the bin directory (Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\bin).

[libmysql Library Download Link](http://wiltonsoftware.com/download/libmysql-5.1.59-win32.zip)

Answer (score 3):

You should never place any 3rd party files in the bin directory  - XE3 does not allow this 
[Please Read this document](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Release_Notes_for_XE3#Do_not_install_extraneous_files_in_.5Cbin_directories)